# NAND and NOR logic gates

Tags: digital-logic

What would be the diagram of following logic gate function by using NAND and NOR IC’s?

F = AB + BC + AC.

Kindly help how to draw its logic diagram?

Comment: The drawing is the easy part - first you need to apply Boolean identities to transform it to use NAND and NOR. Specifically, take a look at De Morgan's law.

Comment: For you its easy but not for me. How much NAND and NOR hates would be used?Would the two inputs be taken as common?

Comment: Why use NAND and NOR - AND and OR are simpler

Comment: @user3351862: Again, the answer to those two questions will be immediately apparent once you apply De Morgan's law.

Comment: @Andyaka: Probably it's an academic exercise to show that any combinatorial circuit can be implemented with NANDs, NORs, and inverters

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I'm pretty certain it is too but I'm interested in the OP's answer

Comment: yup,it's an academic exercise.Can anyone provide me its diagram?

Comment: @user3351862; I will do it once I get back from class if no one else has already. In the mean time, please read about Boolean algebra and De Morgan's law.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I read that....

Comment: You should add the Homework tag if this is homework.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard, you just have to apply De Morgan's transformations, as mentioned in the comments.

Take this into account:

- \$ \overline{\overline{A}} = A \$.
- \$ \overline{A+B} = \bar A \cdot \bar B \$ and viceversa
- \$ \overline{A \cdot B} = \bar A + \bar B \$ and viceversa

From that you only need to apply these transformation until you get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

for NAND gate implementation...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7qAbt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

for NOR gate implementation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa3aXf.png)</sup>